# How to find edges hierarchy graph from directed acyclic graph in python

Tags: python, networkx

I have data as following:
[image]

I want a new graph as follows:
[image]
Which represents edges hierarchy of the previous graph.

Comment: Can someone please tell me what an edge hierarchy graph is? Googling didn't help.

Comment: @J...S Excuse me for my English. Those are made-up words. What I mean to say is if we arrange the nodes of the 1st graph in topological order, the 2nd graph represents edges that cover the most separated nodes(this will be root,  2nd most separated(child nodes) and so on, in a tree(or graph with edges from above, being nodes here) representation.  Picture 1st graph as a single bus route, with nodes as stops. The 2nd graph represents routes with the longest distance, followed by overlapping 2nd longest(2nd level), and so on.

Comment: As your example illustrates, there can be multiple edge hierarchy graphs for a given DAG (both, 'a' and 'b', could be the root in your DAG). Are you looking for all possible solutions or just one?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, all possible

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct the graph with edges between nodes in original graph as nodes and nodes in original graphs as edges, as I understand. In this case, your graph in post is incorrect. For example: you have node `be`, which is a successor of `ae`, but in original graph it is not true, `ae` and `be` are parallel. I constructed a code to solve this problem:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
from itertools import groupby

# Create a random DAG
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(10,0.3,directed=True)
DAG = nx.DiGraph([(u,v) for (u,v) in G.edges() if u<v])

res = nx.DiGraph()
# Create nodes in new DAG as edges in original DAG
res.add_nodes_from(list(DAG.edges()))
sorted_res_nodes = sorted(res.nodes, key=lambda x: x[1])

# Connect all nodes with end of node1 is equal to start of node2
for n1 in sorted_res_nodes:
    for n2 in sorted_res_nodes:
        if n1[1] == n2[0]:
            res.add_edge(n1, n2)

# Draw graphs
nx.draw(
    DAG,
    with_labels=True,
    pos=nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(
        DAG, prog='dot'
    )
)
nx.draw(
    res,
    with_labels=True,
    pos=nx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(
        res, prog='dot'
    )
)
```

For this graph:

[image]

The new graph will be constructed:

[image]

Note, that all edges from roots in original DAG transformed into roots in new DAG. Also note that for every edge the end of the start node is equal to the start of the end node.